# Como crear un hash de una tabla html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buen día, mi duda surge sobre una tabla html en la cual estoy almacenando los pagos de nomina de una empresa, sin embargo participan distintos modelos sobre esta vista, mi duda principalmente recide en como poder enviar los tr y td generados en mi tabla al controlador para posteriormente poder separar los distintos hash y guardarlos en su modelo correspondiente.

Mi tabla es esta:

```
<table id = "mytable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Week</th>
          <th>Employee</th>
          <th>Department</th>
          <th>obra</th>
          <th class:'totaldias' style="display: true;" id= "jueves">Jueves</th>
          <th class:'totaldias' id= "viernes">Viernes</th>
          <th class:'totaldias' id= "sabado">Sabado</th>
          <th class:'totaldias' id= "domingo">Domingo</th>
          <th class:'totaldias' id= "lunes">Lunes</th>
          <th class:'totaldias' id= "martes">Martes</th>
          <th class:'totaldias' id= "miercoles">Miercoles</th>
          <th class:'totaldias' id= "total-dias">Dias trabajados</th>
          <th class:'totaldias' id= "vacaciones">Dias vacaciones</th>
          <th class:'totaldias' id= "faltas">Faltas</th>
          <th><%= link_to "Total Sueldo Bruto","#", id: "mostrarDias", remote: true%></th><!-- 13 -->
          <th>Bonos</th>
          <th>Flete</th>
          <th>Incapacidad</th>
          <th>Vacaciones</th>
          <th>Finiquito</th>
          <th>Total percepciones</th><!-- 19 -->
          <th>Caja de Ahorro</th>
          <th>Prestamo Aporta</th>
          <th>Prestamo</th>
          <th>Comida</th>
          <th>Uniforme</th>
          <th>Pensión Alimenticia</th>
          <th>Infonavit</th>
          <th>Fonacot</th>
          <th>Total retenciones</th><!-- 28 -->
          <th>Sueldo fiscal</th>
          <th>Total sueldo neto</th>
          <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>


      <tbody>
        <% @payroll.each do |payroll| %>

            <div style= "display: none"><%= ad = ad(payroll.id) %></div>
          <tr>
            <th><%= payroll.week_id %></th>
            <th><%= payroll.employee.fullname %></th>
            <th><%= payroll.department.name %></th>
            <th><%= payroll.employee_wd.construction_work.name rescue 'base' %></th>
            <td class:'totaldias' contenteditable= true onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= payroll.employee_wd.jueves rescue 0 %></td>
            <td class:'totaldias' contenteditable= true onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= payroll.employee_wd.viernes rescue 0%></td>
            <td class:'totaldias' contenteditable= true onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= payroll.employee_wd.sabado rescue 0 %></td>
            <td class:'totaldias' contenteditable= true onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= payroll.employee_wd.domingo rescue 0 %></td>
            <td class:'totaldias' contenteditable= true onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= payroll.employee_wd.lunes rescue 0 %></td>
            <td class:'totaldias' contenteditable= true onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= payroll.employee_wd.martes rescue 0 %></td>
            <td class:'totaldias' contenteditable= true onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= payroll.employee_wd.miercoles rescue 0 %></td>
            <th class:'totaldias'><%= payroll.dias_trabajados %></th><!-- Dias Trabajados    -->
            <th class:'totaldias'><%= payroll.dias_vacaciones %></th><!-- Dias de Vacaciones    -->
            <td class:'totaldias' contenteditable= true ><%= payroll.faltas %></th><!-- Faltas    -->
            <th class:'totaldias'><%= payroll.total_sueldo_bruto %></th><!-- total sueldo bruto    -->


            <td contenteditable= true onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%= ad[0] %></td>
            <td contenteditable= true onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%= ad[1] %></td>
            <td contenteditable= true onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%= ad[2] %></td>
            <td contenteditable= true onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%= ad[3] %></td>
            <td contenteditable= true onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%= ad[4] %></td>
            <th><%= payroll.total_percepciones%></th><!--  Total Percepciones   -->
            <td contenteditable= true onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= ad[5] %></td>
            <td contenteditable= true onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= ad[6] %></td>
            <td contenteditable= true onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= ad[7] %></td>
            <td contenteditable= true onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= ad[8] %></td>
            <td contenteditable= true onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= ad[9] %></td>
            <td contenteditable= true onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= ad[10] %></td>
            <td contenteditable= true onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= ad[11] %></td>
            <td contenteditable= true onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= ad[12] %></td>
            <th><%= payroll.total_retenciones %></th><!-- total retenciones   -->
            <th><%= payroll.sueldo_fiscal %></th><!-- Sueldo fiscal    -->
            <th><%= payroll.total_sueldo_neto %></th><!--total sueldo neto   -->
            <td>
            <input type="Submit" />
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

O bien si hay alguna gema que pueda utilizar para poder realizar esta acción, soy nuevo en rails y la verdad no tengo idea de como poder realizar esta acción.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

> Editado:

En este caso lo que deseo es poder enviar los datos contenidos en los td contenidos en el tbody, en este caso no se como enviar esta información, se me habia ocurrido hacer un form_for por fila y un for_form que los contenga a todos con el submit que envie la información, pero la verdad desconozco cual sea la mejor forma de hacerlo. En si lo que deseo es enviar los datos que se ingresen a la tabla y a su vez la información contenida en la variable payroll.

Y me refiero con el hash de hashes que deseo enviar todos los renglones contenidos en el tbody con un solo clic en 'guardar', ya que cada renglón seria un registro que hacer de payroll.

> Editado

modifique mi tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
          <tbody>
        <%form_tag({controller: "payrolls", action: "create"}, method: "post", class: "nifty_form", remote: true) do%>
          <% @payroll.each do |payroll| %>

              <div style= "display: none"><%= ad = ad(payroll.id) %></div>
            <tr>
              <td><%=(:week_id,  payroll.week_id) %></th>
              <td><%= text_field_tag(:employee_name, payroll.employee.fullname) %></th>
              <td><%=text_field_tag(:department_name,  payroll.department.name) %></th>

              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= text_field_tag(:jueves, payroll.employee_wd.jueves)%></td>
              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= text_field_tag(:viernes, payroll.employee_wd.viernes)%></td>
              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= text_field_tag(:sabado, payroll.employee_wd.sabado) %></td>
              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%=text_field_tag(:domingo, payroll.employee_wd.domingo) %></td>
              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= text_field_tag(:lunes,payroll.employee_wd.lunes) %></td>
              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= text_field_tag(:martes, payroll.employee_wd.martes)%></td>
              <td onblur=sumDias(getRowIndex(this)) ><%= text_field_tag(:miercoles, payroll.employee_wd.miercoles) %></td>
              <th><%= text_field_tag(:dias_trabajados, payroll.dias_trabajados) %></th><!-- Dias Trabajados    -->
              <th><%=text_field_tag(:dias_vacaciones,  payroll.dias_vacaciones) %></th><!-- Dias de Vacaciones    -->
              <td><%=text_field_tag(:faltas,  payroll.faltas) %></th><!-- Faltas    -->
              <th><%= text_field_tag(:total_sueldo_bruto, payroll.total_sueldo_bruto) %></th><!-- total sueldo bruto    -->

              <td onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:bonos,  ad[0]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:fletes,  ad[1])%></td>
              <td onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:jueves,  ad[2] )%></td>
              <td onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:incapacidad,  ad[3]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adSum(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:finiquito,  ad[4]) %></td>
              <td><%=text_field_tag(:total_percepciones,  payroll.total_percepciones)%></th><!--  Total Percepciones   -->

              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:caja_ahorro,  ad[5]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:prestamo_aporta,  ad[6]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:prestamo,  ad[7] )%></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%=text_field_tag(:comida,  ad[8]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= text_field_tag(:uniforme, ad[9]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= text_field_tag(:pension_alimenticia, ad[10] )%></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= text_field_tag(:infonavit, ad[11]) %></td>
              <td onblur=adRest(getRowIndex(this))><%= text_field_tag(:fonacot, ad[12]) %></td>
              <td><%=text_field_tag(:total_retenciones,  payroll.total_retenciones) %></th><!-- total retenciones   -->

              <td><%=text_field_tag(:sueldo_fiscal,  payroll.sueldo_fiscal) %></th><!-- Sueldo fiscal    -->
              <td><%= text_field_tag(:total_sueldo_neto, payroll.total_sueldo_neto) %></th><!--total sueldo neto   -->
          <% end %>
          <%= submit_tag("guardar") %>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
```

Sin embargo me muestra la pagina sin datos ni formulario que llenar, solamente los encabezados de la tabla ya que esos estan fuera del . Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿Cómo generas la tabla?

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con enviar los tr y td?¿Quieres enviar el contenido de esos elementos? ¿enviar el html generado?¿hacer los td editables y enviar la info a través de un formulario? no logré entender lo que quieres. Y ¿a que te refieres con separar los distintos hash? mas bien ¿a que hashes te refieres?. Explícate más lo que quieres o mas información si quieres recibir más ayuda

Comment: @Alter-Lagos ya edite mi pregunta un poco a mas detalle para ver si es un poco mas claro lo que requiero hacer

Comment: @Gerry aun no tengo alguna idea de como poder enviar o recibir los datos en el controlador, solamente tengo el html con los pagos de la semana, los cuales el usuario modificara y al momento de guardar necesito enviar todos los pagos de esa semana contenidos en el <tbody> por cada renglon es un pago, entonces ocupo poder enviar todos los pagos y a su vez separarlos al momento de recibirlos ya que hay varios modelos involucrados en los datos que se generan a partir de cada pago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo entender lo que quieres. Lo mejor es crear un único form y anidar tus asociaciones dentro de él en vez de hacer forms por cada fila (a menos que de verdad lo requieras). Si no sabes como hacer formularios anidados, en la [documentación de Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms) sale los cambios que deberías realizar. Ahora respecto al problema en sí, las opciones que veo son:

- Si usas `contenteditable` en los td, eso no lo puedes llegar y enviar en un formulario. Debes crear inputs de tipo hidden por cada uno de tus td editables y usar js para poder copiar el contenido. Hacer algo como:

  ```
  function copyContent () {
      document.getElementById("tuInputOculto").value =  
          document.getElementById("tuTdEditable").innerHTML;
      return true;
  }


  <form action='whatever' onsubmit='return copyContent()'>
  ```
- En vez de usar `<td contenteditable= true>...</td>`, simplemente usa `<td><input/></td>` dentro de tu tabla y con css ajustas el estilo del input para que parezca más parte de la tabla y no un input.
- Usar una librería js que te cree tablas editables. No te sabría recomendar, ya que nunca he usado una, pero podrías revisar [alguna de estas](http://jster.net/tag/grid) o simplemente [googlear](https://www.google.cl/search?q=js+editable+table&oq=js+editable+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4247j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Si me preguntas, me iría por la opción dos ya que es mas fácil de implementar dentro de lo que es el ecosistema rails. La opción 3 yo "creo" que las librerías deben ser muy similares a la opción uno respecto a lo que hacen las librerías por debajo, pero hecho fácil, aunque claro, está la curva de aprendizaje de usar una nueva librería, pero puede llegar a ser una buena opción si buscas bien.La uno la veo bastante engorrosa lo de crear N inputs por td editable que exista y luego manejarlo con js, pero sigue siendo una opción si es que quieres seguir en la  linea que ya empezaste.

Comment: Muy bien, para seguir tu recomendación solo tengo una duda, en mi submit o form for como envio esos inputs? Es que eso es lo que aun no logro comprender en la 'magia' de rails, como le paso esos inputs al controlador de cada linea, o es necesario hacer un submit por cada renglon en la tabla?

Comment: No necesitas enviar cada linea a su controlador, puedes enviar todo a un mismo controlador, independiente de que no sean los mismos modelos del controlador, siempre que esos modelos estén asociados con el modelo del controlador. Te insisto, revisa la documentación de rails que te adjunté, ahí sale como hacer lo que requieres. Si es por el inglés, googlea "formularios anidados en rails" o "rails formularios con form_tag" si no entiendes como hacer formularios sin `form_for`, pero no es algo que vaya a explicar en una respuesta, requiere estudiarlo porque es parte de la base de rails.

Comment: Si gracias estaba revisando la documentación y efectivamente esta muy bien explicado como funciona probare esta forma y les cuento como me fue.

Comment: disculpa hice lo del form_tag  pero ahora no me muestra nada, creo que posiblemente lo este haciendo mal, aunque no me marca ningun error, adjunto el codigo que modifique.

Comment: Te faltó el signo = antes de form_tag. Te recomiendo de todas formas que para la próxima crees una nueva pregunta en vez de modificar la ya existente, ya que no siempre estará disponible para seguir respondiendo quien ya te respondió y siempre hay más gente dispuesta a ayudar. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, es que no sabia si contaría como una pregunta duplicada, de igual forma gracias de nuevo. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar javascript/jQuery para leer los valores de la tabla, guardarlos dentro de una forma (en `input` tipo `hidden`) y enviar esa forma.

Checa el siguiente ejemplo, para el cual utilizo una versión reducida y simplificada de tu tabla.

#### Tabla

Primero debemos asegurarnos que podamos identificar claramente a que `payroll` pertenece cada registro, y esto lo podemos lograr agregando el atributo `name` en cada `td`:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <% @payroll.each do |payroll| %>
      <tr>
        <td name="<%= payroll.id %>" class='totaldias' contenteditable='true'><%= payroll.employee_wd.jueves rescue 0 %></td>
        <td name="<%= payroll.id %>" class='totaldias' contenteditable='true'><%= payroll.employee_wd.viernes rescue 0 %></td>
        <td name="<%= payroll.id %>" class='totaldias' contenteditable='true'><%= payroll.employee_wd.sabado rescue 0 %></td>
        <td name="<%= payroll.id %>" class='totaldias'><%= payroll.dias_trabajados %></td>
        <td name="<%= payroll.id %>" class='totaldias'><%= payroll.dias_vacaciones %></td>
        <td name="<%= payroll.id %>" class='totaldias' contenteditable='true'><%= payroll.faltas %></td>
        <td name="<%= payroll.id %>" class='totaldias'><%= payroll.total_sueldo_bruto %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Forma

Necesitamos generar una forma que contenga un `input` tipo `hidden` para cada uno de los `payroll` disponibles, por lo tanto también debe ser dinámica<sup>1</sup>:

```
<form id="my-form" action="/tu_accion" method="post">
  <% @payroll.each do |payroll| %>
    <input type="hidden" id="table_<%= payroll.id %>" name="table[<%= payroll.id %>]">
  <% end %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
  <input type="button" id="envia-forma" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

El atributo `id` en el `input` nos sirve para identificar el `input` adecuado al momento de agrupar los datos; el atributo que `name` nos sirve para poder reconocer el grupo en el controlador (a través de `params[payroll.id]`)

#### Script

Por último agreguemos el script (utilizo jQuery en este ejemplo) para poder asignar los valores en la forma y enviarla:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#envia-forma").click(function(){
      $("td.totaldias").each( function() {
        let name  = $(this).attr('name');
        let value = $(this).html();

        $("#table_" + name).val($("#table_" + name).val() + value + ",")
      });

    $("#my-form").submit();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Finalmente, en tu controlador podrás buscar los valores de los `td` en `params`, los cuales recibirás separados por comma y agrupados por `payroll.id`; por ejemplo (para un payroll con `p1` como valor de `id`:

```
values = params[:p1].chomp(",").split(",")
#=> ["valortd1", "valortd2", ...]
```

Y `values` tendrá un arreglo con los valores de cada `td` que pertenecen al `payroll` con `p1`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Gerry la verdad tu respuesta se adecuaba mas a lo que tenia, aunque creo que modificare el código para hacer un form_tag ya que creo que usaria un codigo mas apegado a rails. Sin embargo te agradezco demasiado el tiempo que te tomas en contestar

Comment: @DanielRomero Lo importante es que encuentres la mejor solución a tu problema. Suerte!